# Player freezes mid air when not also moving with WASD

Tags: unity, c#

Current issue: Player freezes mid air unless you are also using WASD to move around. Also, if you are not moving and you press space it wont jump until you start to move. Here is my script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class ThirdPersonPlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;
    public Transform camera;
    public Transform groundCheck;

    Vector3 direction;
    Vector3 velocity;

    public float moveSpeed = 10f;
    public float turnSmoothTime = 0.1f;
    private float turnSmoothVelocity;
    public float gravity = -39.24f;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public float jumpHeight = 3f;

    public LayerMask groundMask;
    private bool isGrounded;

    // Update is called once per frame
    // Unity is currently working on a new input system***
    private void Update()
    {
        IsPlayerGrounded();

        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        direction = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized; // direction player is moving

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            Jump();
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MoveAndRotate();
    }


    private void MoveAndRotate()
    {
        if (direction.magnitude >= 0.1f)
        {
            float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + camera.eulerAngles.y;
            float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, ref turnSmoothVelocity, turnSmoothTime);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f);
            //  Testing out gravity and this function as one

            Gravity();

            // end test
            Vector3 moveDirection = Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngle, 0f) * Vector3.forward;

            

            controller.Move(moveDirection.normalized * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime + velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }
    }

    // Implemented proper gravity from /_\ y = 1/2g * t^2
    private void Gravity()
    {
        velocity.y += gravity * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

        /*controller.Move(velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);*/
    }

    // Check if player is grounded and reset velocity 
    private void IsPlayerGrounded()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

        if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }
    }

    private void Jump()
    {
        velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I cannot seem to find any logical reason as to why this is happening!

[image]

Comment: Hint: If `direction` is a zero vector, when do you apply `Gravity()`?

Comment: I thought that when using controller.Move it would apply the gravity regardless of if the direction is 0 thus you are just standing still ;-; I am a newbie so maybe I'm assuming the wrong things

Comment: I assume because of the controller.Move having a * Time.fixedDelta time as the last part of it, it's making it 0 when they're not moving? If so, I don't understand how you could apply both. I had 2 separate controller.Move running before, but that causes issues like stuttering in collision with another object, and you cant multiply 2 Vector3' ? @DMGregory
Edit: That wouldn't make sense because velocity would not be 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on DMGregory's comments:

In this line of code, `direction` could be (0, 0, 0) if the player has not made any input.

```
direction = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized;
```

Your MoveAndRotate code looks like this:

```
private void MoveAndRotate()
{
    if (direction.magnitude >= 0.1f)
    {
        [...]
        Gravity();
        [...]
        controller.Move(moveDirection.normalized * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime + velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
}
```

Notice that `Gravity()` and `controller.Move()` will only get called if `direction` has a length greater than 0.1, but `direction` can have a length of 0 if the player has not made any input, so `Gravity()` and `controller.Move()` will not be called if the player has not made any input.

Comment: Yes it is. This seems to have been my issue and has resolved it (sort of). Although, jumping acts differently when moving compared to standing still. I have adjusted the code to look like this now:
if (direction.magnitude == 0)
        {
            Gravity();
            controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        
        else if (direction.magnitude >= 0.1f)
        {
            Same as before
        }

Comment: Thanks for the help you guys! It wont let me upvote it but I have selected it as the correct answer. My jump that I just mentioned was just me adding gravity twice lol.